# Snake Game score not adding

Tags: turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This snake game code. I want to add the system score in this game. So that each time the snake eating his score would be increased. But if the snake does not get food score will not increase.

How do I go about displaying the current score?

this is :
""" A simple snake game using Turtle Graphics. """
import turtle
import math
import random

```
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
FOOD_SIZE = 10
DELAY = 100  # milliseconds

offsets = {
    "up": (0, 20),
    "down": (0, -20),
    "left": (-20, 0),
    "right": (20, 0)
}
```

scores are not updating
def addscore():
global score
score += 1

```
def reset():
    global snake, snake_direction, food_pos, pen
    snake = [[0, 0], [0, 20], [0, 40], [0, 60], [0, 80]]
    snake_direction = "up"
    food_pos = get_random_food_pos()
    food.goto(food_pos)
    #screen.update() Only needed if we are fussed about drawing food before next call to `draw_snake()`.
    move_snake()
 
def move_snake():
    global snake_direction

    #  Next position for head of snake.
    new_head = snake[-1].copy()
    new_head[0] = snake[-1][0] + offsets[snake_direction][0]
    new_head[1] = snake[-1][1] + offsets[snake_direction][1]

    # Check self-collision
    if new_head in snake[:-1]:  # Or collision with walls?
        reset()
    else:
        # No self-collision so we can continue moving the snake.
        snake.append(new_head)

        # Check food collision
        if not food_collision():
            snake.pop(0)  # Keep the snake the same length unless fed.
```

wrapping up

```
        #  Allow screen wrapping
        if snake[-1][0] > WIDTH / 2:
            snake[-1][0] -= WIDTH
        elif snake[-1][0] < - WIDTH / 2:
            snake[-1][0] += WIDTH
        elif snake[-1][1] > HEIGHT / 2:
            snake[-1][1] -= HEIGHT
        elif snake[-1][1] < -HEIGHT / 2:
            snake[-1][1] += HEIGHT

        # Clear previous snake stamps
        pen.clearstamps()

        # Draw snake
        for segment in snake:
            pen.goto(segment[0], segment[1])
            pen.stamp()

        # Refresh screen
        screen.update()

        # Rinse and repeat
        turtle.ontimer(move_snake, DELAY)
 
def food_collision():
    global food_pos
    if get_distance(snake[-1], food_pos) < 20:
        food_pos = get_random_food_pos()
        food.goto(food_pos)
        return True
    return False

def get_random_food_pos():
    x = random.randint(- WIDTH / 2 + FOOD_SIZE, WIDTH / 2 - FOOD_SIZE)
    y = random.randint(- HEIGHT / 2 + FOOD_SIZE, HEIGHT / 2 - FOOD_SIZE)
    return (x, y)

def get_distance(pos1, pos2):
    x1, y1 = pos1
    x2, y2 = pos2
    distance = ((y2 - y1) * 2 + (x2 - x1) * 2) ** 0.5
    return distance

def go_up():
    global snake_direction
    if snake_direction != "down":
        snake_direction = "up"

def go_right():
    global snake_direction
    if snake_direction != "left":
        snake_direction = "right"

def go_down():
    global snake_direction
    if snake_direction != "up":
        snake_direction = "down"

def go_left():
    global snake_direction
    if snake_direction != "right":
        snake_direction = "left"

# Screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.title("Snake")
screen.bgcolor("green")
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.tracer(0)

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle("square")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 250)
pen.write("Score : 0  High Score : 0", align="center", font=("candara", 24, "bold"))
  
# Food
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.shape("circle")
food.color("red")
food.shapesize(FOOD_SIZE / 20)  # Default size of turtle "square" shape is 20.
food.penup()

# Event handlers
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(go_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(go_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(go_down, "Down")
screen.onkey(go_left, "Left")

# Let's go
reset()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's defined, but you have to call your `addscore()` function.  Replace

```
if not food_collision():
    snake.pop(0)
```

with

```
if food_collision():
    addscore()
else:
    snake.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this code to your game. It will write a score:

```
score = 0
#Creating Score Writer
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.color("white")
turtle.goto(-300,300)
turtle.write(f"Score = {score}", font=("Arial",16,"normal"))
```

You also don't need a screen.setup() for this.
You can change the score variable. Every time you want the text to update you write

```
turtle.clear()
turtle.write(f"Score = {score}", font=("Arial",16,"normal"))
```

Comment: scores are not updating

Comment: You can add a variable called score = 0, Then you can change that score and write the turtle.write again